# Ruby on Rails's content_for will do an automatic HTML escape?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, content-for

Using Rails 3.0.6, I found that in the view, if I do a

```
content_for :food_name, "Macaroni & Cheese"
```

Then when I get it back using `content_for(:food_name)`, then the `&` will be made into `&amp;` already.
It doesn't matter if I do a `content_for(:food_name).html_safe`, the `&` is still made into `&amp;` already.

But if done the following way, then it is not escaped:

```
content_for :food_name, "Macaroni & Cheese".html_safe
```

In this case, the `&` will not change to `&amp;` automatically.  Now, because there are places where
I actually do a `#{h content_for(:food_name)}` and it will be escaped twice (to become `&amp;amp;`), or
**because I have values in `<meta>` description, it will be strange to call `h` on some values and not call it
on some other values**.

Also, one big catch is, **if it escapes automatically, and what if I add `" - come see us!"` to the end of it, and rely on Rails 3 to escape it, now then, the `&` is escaped twice**.

In the `content_for` docs:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-content_for

I don't see any description like that.  So is the description above correct
or is the docs more correct -- that in fact there is no automatic HTML escape?

It seems like from the source code on the above webpage, `content_for` calls `capture`, and it does an `ERB::Util.html_escape`,
so there is in fact an automatic escape, but should there really be, and why?  Is it also not documented that `capture`  does an
automatic escape?

Comment: On a sidenote, for storing simple values (like value of a meta tag), I often use a instance variable instead. `content_for` seems to be designed for html fragments in mind.

Answer (score 3):

Use `<%= raw some_stuff %>` when you don't want Rails to escape these characters, otherwise use the simple call.

You always know the areas where the content can be such, that could be modified if escaped, so you can simply fit in`raw` at those places.

For more information, refer to this really great article by Yehuda katz.
[safebuffers-and-rails-3-0](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/02/01/safebuffers-and-rails-3-0/)

Comment: while are are some other info, I was hoping to get some idea about the behavior of `content_for`