# Returning javascript from rails helper

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails-3

I am having problems returning javascript from helper functions. I am unable to get the following test case to work:

function in helpers/application_helper.rb

```
def show_stuff
    return '$("div#flash").html("<p> stuff </p>");'
end
```

now I try to call this helper function in general.js.erb

```
<%= show_stuff %>
```

Here is the output

```
$(&quot;div#flash&quot;).html(&quot;&lt;p&gt; stuff &lt;/p&gt;&quot;);
```

I've also tried show_stuff.html_safe and raw show_stuff and had no luck. I feel the issue is Rails auto-escaping html but have been unable to find a solution.

Comment: Try [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932267/dont-escape-html-in-ruby-on-rails) and/or [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811488/ruby-on-railss-content-for-will-do-an-automatic-html-escape). Also, note that your ruby method doesn't need `return` since it always returns the last line's value anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ERB is escaping the characters in your outputted Javascript.

To prevent this happening use the `raw` method in your template.

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
    <%= raw(show_stuff) %>
<% end %>
```

I've added the `javascript_tag` method around this for context.